# error on #include <filesystem> on clang 6 and 10

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

I'm getting this:

```
No such file or directory
 #include <filesystem>
```

on

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
#include <filesystem>
#endif
```

when trying to compile with clang 6.0. Unfortunately I cannot move to `experimental/filesystem` because it's not my library, it's OpenVPN3. I tried with clang 10 and still got the error.

What are my options if I can't modify OpenVPN3?

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(ovpncli)

set (PROJECT_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_ROOT}/openvpn3/cmake;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
include(findcoredeps)
set(LIBTINS_BUILD_SHARED OFF CACHE BOOL "enable X functionality" FORCE)
set(LIBTINS_ENABLE_PCAP OFF CACHE BOOL "enable X functionality" FORCE)
set(PCAP_INCLUDE_DIR "")
set(PCAP_LIBRARY "")
add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_ROOT}/libtins _libtins)
add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_ROOT}/literal_ipaddr _literal_ipaddr)
add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_ROOT}/smoltcp_cpp_interface smoltcp_cpp_interface)

set(KOVPN_SOURCE "${CORE_DIR}/../kovpn" CACHE PATH "ovpn-dco kernel module source tree")
include_directories(${PROJECT_ROOT}/openvpn3/)
include_directories(${PROJECT_ROOT}/libtins/include)
include_directories(${PROJECT_ROOT}/asio/asio/include)
include_directories(${PROJECT_ROOT}/literal_ipaddr)


add_executable(libopenvpn_example OpenVPNClient.cpp)
add_dependencies(libopenvpn_example tins literal_ipaddr)
set_property(TARGET libopenvpn_example PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
target_link_libraries(libopenvpn_example tins literal_ipaddr)
add_core_dependencies(libopenvpn_example)
```

Verbose:

```
cd /workspaces/libopenvpnclient/build/src && /usr/local/clang/bin/clang++  -DASIO_STANDALONE -DHAVE_LZ4 -DLZ4_DISABLE_DEPRECATE_WARNINGS -DMBEDTLS_DEPRECATED_REMOVED -DUSE_ASIO -DUSE_OPENSSL -I/workspaces/libopenvpnclient/src/../openvpn3 -I/workspaces/libopenvpnclient/src/../libtins/include -I/workspaces/libopenvpnclient/src/../asio/asio/include -I/workspaces/libopenvpnclient/src/../literal_ipaddr -I/workspaces/libopenvpnclient/openvpn3/cmake/.. -I/workspaces/libopenvpnclient/openvpn3/cmake/../../deps/asio/asio/include  -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wno-missing-field-initializers -std=c++1z -o CMakeFiles/libopenvpn_example.dir/OpenVPNClient.cpp.o -c /workspaces/libopenvpnclient/src/OpenVPNClient.cpp
```

Comment: You probably don't have a C++17 standard library installed.  Have you verified that?

Comment: @StephenNewell you mean libstdc++6? `libstdc++6 is already the newest version`

Comment: Does the version installed have `filesystem`?  I build fine on my system with clang-9 and clang-10, with both libstdc++ and libc++ (x86_64 Gentoo).

Comment: @StephenNewell I just downloaded the version 10 binaries from https://releases.llvm.org/download.html and setted `export CC=/usr/local/clang/bin/clang && export CXX=/usr/local/clang/bin/clang++ ` and then `cmake .. && make`

Comment: So your standard library is probably out of date.  Check with your linux distro for an update.

Comment: @StephenNewell rebuilding now with ubuntu 20 on docker, let's see. But shouldn't the C++ libraries be the ones used by clang? Maybe I should set the library path too? I tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/clang/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` then run cmake then make but the error persists. I do not like building with very new Ubuntu becaus then it'll not work on older ones

Comment: Did you install libc++?  I've never used the binaries provided by the llvm project, but my experience is that it defaults to the more common library used by the OS (for linux, libstdc++).

Comment: @StephenNewell installing libc++6 on ubuntu 18 didnt solve the problem. Using ubuntu 20 without installing it worked. However compiling on ubuntu 18 would be much better for compatibility

Comment: You're going to need to get a version of libstdc++ with the C++17 headers installed.  Your best bet for that is probably Ubuntu's documentation or askubuntu.com.  Using libc++ will cause problems if you have to interact with any libraries that are built against libstdc++.

Answer (score 0):

If using `libstdc++` verify you have at least version 9 or add `-lstdc++fs`...

Runtime Library (libstdc++)

- Improved support for C++17, including:

  - The C++17 implementation is no longer experimental.
  - Parallel algorithms and `<execution>` (requires Thread Building Blocks 2018 or
    newer).
  - `<memory_resource>`.
  - Using the types and functions in `<filesystem>` does not require linking with -lstdc++fs now.

ref: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html#libstdcxx